# iphone - Problem adding subview to app window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

So I have done several apps where I have done something like this in the appDidFinishLaunching: method

```
[self.window addSubview:someView.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This has worked in the past, but for some reason in my most recent endeavor, when I add the subview, there is a space at the bottom, until I rotate the device.  The space looks like it is the size of the info bar at the top.  My guess is the frame is not updating based on the device orientation and location of the info bar.  I am not manipulating the view in any other way other then adding it as a subview. Anyone have any idea what might be going on??  Thanks..!

[Check out this screenshot of it in action...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVaS.png)

Comment: Is the space at the bottom appearing immediately at startup of your app?

Comment: Yeah, until I rotate the device.  Then I assume the frames update, and it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand that someView is a controller? check if you return *anything* in the controller for function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
```

Comment: Do you hide status bar in appDidFinishLaunching. If so make sure you do the same in .list file  UIStatusBarHidden or similat to NO

Comment: No, my status bar is always shown.  I never adjusted that value.  I am really confused why it appears to think it's on the bottom?  Have you looked at the screen I posted?

Comment: BTW, the view was indeed created in IB, and set to "Scale to Fill"

Comment: Is it possible that accidentally you edited window view in IB or change TabController frame

Comment: Naw, the window view is unchanged from the default, and I don't believe I modified the TabBar frame...

Comment: See solution below.  Thanks for the help ;)